# Approximating the angle between the trajectory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I started to learn physics this semester and I found the following task:

A contestant is participating in a half-maraton tournament(straight line length $L =21095$ meter) running in a zig-zag manner (constantly surpassing other contestants), holding a stable angle $\alpha$ between the trajectory. After finishing the run, the contestant has noticed that the distance travelled was 500 meters longer than $L$. Approximate the angle $\alpha$ without using a calculator.

I have no idea how to approach this problem so any help would be useful.

Comment: I think a sketch would be helpful. Also, unless I'm visualizing this wrong, there are infinite angles possible depending on the number of times the contestant zig zags and the length of each zig zag

Comment: You'd need more constraints to solve for a particular $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The green line is the line that the "zig-zag" runner is running.

Thus:

$$s\cos(\alpha)=a\tag 1$$

So if he is doing this n times during the half-marathon you obtain
that:

$$n\,(s-a)=\Delta L\tag 2$$

With Eq. (1) and (2) you obtain that:

$$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{a\,n}{\Delta L+a\,n}$$

**Edit**

with the remarks from @AgniusVasiliauskas

$$a\,n=L~\Rightarrow \\(\alpha)=\frac{L}{\Delta L+L}\approx 0^\circ $$

Comment: In problem description is mentioned that marathon is on *straight line* instead of arc which is pictured in your answer. Also $na=L$, so your formula could be replaced into simpler expression $$\cos(\alpha) = \frac {L}{\Delta L + L}$$, but other than that - great solution !

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas I see thanks

Comment: @Eli Why is $\frac{L}{\delta L + L}$ equal to $12$?

Comment: This is the result with your data $~L~$ and $~\Delta L~$ , $\alpha=~12^\circ$
not $~\cos(\alpha)~$ but $\alpha$ sorry for that i correct the document

Comment: @Eli Well, L is equal to $21095$ and $L + \Delta L = 21595$. I still don't see how did you get the $12$ degrees. Could you explain this a little bit more, please? Thank you.

Comment: I mean, we could probably calculate the arccos of (21095/21595) but that would require a calculator.

Comment: i see this is wrong cos is approximately 1 so alpha is zero

Comment: $\begin{aligned}\cos \left( \dfrac{21095}{500+21095}\right) \simeq 1.000\\
\arccos \left( 1\right) =0\end{aligned}$

Answer (score 0):

The angle is small but it is not zero. The problem relies on the fact that the angle is small when it asks to find an approximate value without using a calculator.
You find $cos(\alpha)=\frac{L}{L+\Delta L} \approx 0.977 $.
But, for small angles, you can approximate $cos(\alpha) \approx 1-\frac{\alpha^2}{2} $
So, by comparing the two relationships, you can get the angle in radians as
$\alpha \approx 0.21 rad$.
To find it in degrees you just multiply by $180/\pi$ (or about 57 or even more roughly, 60) and indeed you get an angle of aproximately $12^0$.
If you are not familiar with the Taylor expansion for cosine function, you can just use $sin^2 +cos^2 =1 $  to find $sin(\alpha)$ and then use the fact that for small angles $sin(\alpha) \approx \alpha$. This is also a result of a Taylor expansion hovewer it is used in introductory Physics in the study of the pendulum so it is more familiar for the students, I believe.